# How can I clear all asp:textboxes on a page when one is onfocus?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a search page that has a few different textboxes that my codebehind uses to search a database.  If the user starts typing in one textbox, I need the other textboxes to clear.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAppID" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxContractID" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxVIN" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You can do this using `JavaScript`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample code?

Comment: Yeah, Got stuck in some work. Have posted my version too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
     $('input[type="text"]').not(this).val("");
 });
```

Please note I have done this for all the textboxes, but you can anyways replace it with respective id's.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".TextBoxSearch").change(function () {
                $(".TextBoxSearch").not('#' + $(this).attr('id')).val('');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAppID" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxContractID" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxVIN" CssClass="TextBoxSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: You're just a superhero.